# How to get top n similar words from given list of words to a vector using gensim?

Tags: java, python, gensim, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I have a use case where I want to find top n nearest words from a given set of words, to a vector.

Its like `similar_by_vector` where I want to restrict my vocab to a given set of words.

```
similar_by_vector(vector, topn, vocab=[x,y,z...])
```

I want to create a low latency api using this, where vocab can be different for each request.
Any suggestions to how I can achieve this optimally?

Comment: Is there a fixed set of vocabularies? If so, some preprocessing can help cutting down processing time. How large are the vocabularies? How long are the words included? How large is the `vector`?

Comment: How big is your total vector-set, and the individual vocabulary subsets? Have you tried just getting the ranked list of all similarities, then filtering by your vocab, and if so, what was wrong with that approach? Or, if the subsets are very small compared to the whole set of word-vectors, just manually calculating the similarity to each word, then sorting the results yourself?

Comment: @vonbrand Yes the vocabularies set are fixed, but they can be many vocabulary sets, around 3000 different vocabulary sets. Length of vocab is max 2000 words. vectors are of 64 dimensions

Comment: Total number of words are 70,000 and the number words in vocabulary sets can be from 500-2000. I tried calculating similarity to each word, and it was a bit time taking as the vocab size increased towards 2000. So just wanted to check if there is some alternative.